# Using Eulers relations to solve complex number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been presented with the following expression, $z^4=-4$

I do not know where to begin with it.
Please could someone explain the methodology to solve this problem?

Comment: What you wrote is not Euler's relation, it is a mere expression that tells you nothing. And it won't be enough for your exercise. Have a look at the polar form of complex numbers.

Comment: You can use de Moivre's theorem for the polar form of a complex no. which i think you have tried to use.

Answer (score 1):

When we assume $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\text{z}=\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}\tag1$$

Where $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now, when we want to solve:

$$\text{z}^4=-4\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{z}=\left|-4\right|^\frac{1}{4}e^{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\arg\left(-4\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}=4^\frac{1}{4}e^{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(-\pi+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}\tag2$$

Where $\text{k}:0-3$.

Comment: Well done, nice answer +1 :) maat